After deleting an event in Google Calendar using GAS, send the contents to any email address through a spreadsheet
Currently, when you create or update an event on Google Calendar, an email notification is sent to any email address, but when you delete an event, you do not receive an email notification.
The specifications are as follows.

You will now receive a notification even if you change an existing schedule.
As a workaround to avoid receiving two emails with the same notification,
Even if multiple scripts are started with one event object, the subsequent scripts will be interrupted.
The date and time of the previous and current notifications, the calendar name, and the update date and time for each individual schedule are now displayed in the email.
-Even if there are multiple schedule updates, they will be combined into one email.
Only calendars with triggers set are processed.

Below is the GAS code.
function monitorMyCalendar(e) {
  if (e) {
    try {
      const isNotExist = 'No';

      const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
      lock.waitLock(0);

      const properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
      const lastUpdated = new Date(properties.getProperty('lastUpdated'));
      const noticedDate = formatDate_(lastUpdated);

      const currentTime = new Date();
      const currentDate = formatDate_(currentTime);

      const today = new Date();
      today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      const twoWeeksLater = new Date(today);
      twoWeeksLater.setDate(twoWeeksLater.getDate() + 14);
      const sixMonthsLater = new Date(today);
      sixMonthsLater.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 6);

      const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(e.calendarId);
      const events = calendar.getEvents(today, sixMonthsLater);

      let noticeCount = 0;
      const mailBodies = [];
      const twoWeeksMap = new Map();

      for (const event of events) {
        const eventUpdated = event.getLastUpdated();
        const isNewEvent = eventUpdated > lastUpdated || event.getStartTime() > lastUpdated;
        if (eventUpdated > twoWeeksLater) {
          break;
        } else if (isNewEvent) {
          twoWeeksMap.set(event.getId(), eventUpdated);
          const eventDetails = {
            title: event.getTitle() || 'title' + isNotExist,
            startTime: event.getStartTime() ? formatDate_(event.getStartTime()) : 'times' + isNotExist,
            endTime: event.getEndTime() ? formatDate_(event.getEndTime()) : 'times' + isNotExist,
            updateTime: formatDate_(eventUpdated),
            description: event.getDescription() || 'detail' + isNotExist,
            location: event.getLocation() || 'plane' + isNotExist,
            url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=' + Utilities.base64Encode(event.getId().split('@')[0] + ' ' + e.calendarId),
            calendarId: e.calendarId,
            calendarName: calendar.getName(),
          };
   
          mailBodies.push(eventDetails);
          noticeCount++;
        }
      }

      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Empty sheet ID");
      const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.calendarId.slice(0, 16)) ?? ss.insertSheet(e.calendarId.slice(0, 16));
      const savedEvents = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      const twoWeeksSavedEvents = savedEvents.filter(data => data[5] >= today && data[5] <= twoWeeksLater);
      const deletedEventIds = [];

      for (const data of twoWeeksSavedEvents) {
        if (!twoWeeksMap.has(data[0])) {
          deletedEventIds.push(data[0]);
        }
      }


      for (const eventId of deletedEventIds) {
        const deletedEventData = savedEvents.find(data => data[0] === eventId);

        if (deletedEventData) {
          const eventDetails = {
            title: deletedEventData[3] || 'title' + isNotExist,
            startTime: deletedEventData[5] ? formatDate_(deletedEventData[5]) : 'times' + isNotExist,
            endTime: deletedEventData[6] ? formatDate_(deletedEventData[6]) : 'times' + isNotExist,
            updateTime: formatDate_(calendar.getEventById(eventId).getLastUpdated()),
            description: deletedEventData[8] || 'Detail' + isNotExist,
            location: deletedEventData[7] || 'Plane' + isNotExist,
            url: '',
            calendarId: e.calendarId,
            calendarName: calendar.getName(),
          };
          mailBodies.push(eventDetails);
          noticeCount++;
          sendDeletedEventNotification_(eventDetails, calendar.getName());
        }
      }

      if (mailBodies.length === 0 && deletedEventIds.length === 0) {
        Logger.log('NEW EVENTS');
      } else {
 
        if (mailBodies.length > 0) {
          mailBodies.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.startTime) - new Date(b.startTime));
          sendEmailNotification_(mailBodies, { noticedDate, currentDate }, properties, lastUpdated);
          properties.setProperty('lastUpdated', currentTime.toISOString());
        }

        if (deletedEventIds.length > 0) {
          sendDeletedEventNotification_(deletedEventIds, calendar.getName());
        }
      }

      if (events.length > 0) {
        const values = events.map(event => [
          event.getId(), 
          calendar.getName(),
          e.calendarId,  
          event.getTitle(), 
          event.getLastUpdated(),
          event.getStartTime(),
          event.getEndTime(),
          event.getLocation(),
          event.getDescription(), 
        ]);
        sheet.clearContents();
        sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
      }

      Utilities.sleep(300);
      lock.releaseLock();

    } catch (error) {
    }
  } else {
    console.log('NO');
  }
}

function formatDate_(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), 'JST', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm');
}

function sendDeletedEventNotification_(eventDetails, calendarName) {
  try {
    const recipientEmail = 'test@gmail.com';
    const subject = "Google";

    if (eventDetails.title && eventDetails.startTime && eventDetails.endTime && eventDetails.location && eventDetails.description) {
      let body = 'Googlecalendar\n' +
          'calendarName: ' + calendarName + '\n\n' +
          'remove: ' + eventDetails.updateTime + '\n' +
          'title: ' + eventDetails.title + '\n' +
          'times: ' + eventDetails.startTime + '\n' +
          'times: ' + eventDetails.endTime + '\n' +
          'plane: ' + eventDetails.location + '\n' +
          'detail: ' + eventDetails.description + '\n\n';

      MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, body);
    } else {
      Logger.log('');
    }
  } catch (error) {
  }
}

function sendEmailNotification_(mailBodies, date, properties, lastUpdated, isNewEvent, isUpdatedEvent, isDeletedEvent) {
  try {
    const lastNotificationDate = new Date(properties.getProperty('lastNotificationDate'));
    const currentTime = new Date();
    let noticeCount = 0;


    if (lastNotificationDate < lastUpdated && currentTime >= lastUpdated && (isNewEvent || isUpdatedEvent || isDeletedEvent)) {
      const recipientEmail = 'test@gmail.com';

      if (isNewEvent || isUpdatedEvent) {
        const subject = isNewEvent ? "";
        let body = '';
        for (const item of mailBodies) {
          body +=
            (isNewEvent ? 'sakusei' : 'kousin') + ': ' + item.updateTime + '\n' +
            'title: ' + item.title + '\n' +
            'times: ' + item.startTime + '\n' +
            'times: ' + item.endTime + '\n' +
            'plane: ' + item.location + '\n' +
            'detail: ' + item.description + '\n\n';
          noticeCount++;
        }
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, body);
      }

      properties.setProperty('lastNotificationDate', currentTime.toISOString());
    }

  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
  }
}



If deletedEvents is not defined, you can check it in the trigger console, but I am at a loss as to how to write the processing here.
Make sure to save it when the script finishes. …① (described later)
When the script starts, it retrieves all future schedules and…②
Next, restore the schedule from ① that was saved at the last startup.
Comparing ① with ②, among the schedules within 2 weeks from the startup date and time
We will notify you by email of any plans that are not listed in ②.
Finally, save all the plans in ②. …New ① (restored at next startup)
*Since it is unknown when the next startup will be,
Get and save all future plans, not just for two weeks.
*After deletion, you will no longer be able to retrieve it.
In ①, save all the items necessary for notifications, such as the ID of each event, title, start date and time, end date and time, location, and details.
Also, multiple event objects occur with one calendar update trigger, so
It will also be necessary to address this issue.
Save all appointments in a spreadsheet, collate all old and new appointments, etc.
Depending on the number of schedules, it may take some time to execute.
The above is the goal, but our goal is to receive email notifications even when a message is "deleted," so we appreciate your cooperation.

I have 3 questions to correctly understand your question. 1. About when you delete an event, you do not receive an email notification, how is the event on Google Calendar deleted? 2. About our goal is to receive email notifications even when a message is "deleted,", what is when a message is "deleted,"? 3. I'm worried that there might be several questions in your question. Can I ask you about the details of your actual question?

Thank you for your comment.



→Added to the spreadsheet when the event is created. At that time, the event ID will be displayed in column A.
When you delete an event on Google Calendar, if it matches the deleted event ID, that email will be sent.



→It has the same meaning as 1.



→Since I don't receive a "deletion" notification, the purpose of this article is to be able to notify you of this.

Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed your reply. So, I proposed a simple modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not your expected result, I apologize.

thank you. You can now delete, update, and delete sheets.
However, I still haven't received the email notification about the "deletion" timing.
The source has also been updated to reflect this modification.

Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand whether my script could detect the deleted events. I think that in your case, first, it is required to detect the deleted events. So, I asked about it. Because if my proposed script cannot detect the deleted events in your situation, it is required to change the approach. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand it. So, I would like to delete my answer once. But, I would like to support you. So, when I can correctly understand your current situation, I would like to propose an answer.

Thank you for your comment.
Your code hints made it possible.
The reference code has been updated.
After event detection, I prepared an email function for delete'' in addition to create, update''.
I'm really thankful to you.
